# Import data from multiple excel files-Oracle PL-SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I wish to import data from excel into oracle table.
But my requirement is I Have multiple excel files and each file contains multiple sheets.
But all have the same structure.

Please let me know the suitable way to perform the same.
Can UTL_FILE utitlity be used to perform this extraction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it directly from Excel.

Actually, *I do*, but **manually**, using TOAD's "Import table data" option. I also don't know what *technique* stands behind the scene, can only guess:
  - it is first temporarily saved as CSV and then loaded
  - Excel files are XML so TOAD manipulates such a data

---

How would I automate it?

- save each worksheet into its own CSV file

  - manual job for me as well. Maybe someone - who knows Excel far better - can write a VBA script or something like that. On the other hand, maybe it is possible to use such a script to directly **insert** data into an Oracle table ... no idea, sorry
- write a **SQL Loader** control file
- load file-by-file, reusing the same control file

  - how to automate that? Use SQL Loader command line `DATA` parameter.
  - how to change it dynamically? Create a wrapper script (on MS Windows, that would be a .BAT script) which would - in a loop - iterate over all those CSV files and *feed* SQL Loader with new data in every iteration

SQL Loader+s advantage over `UTL_FILE` (you mentioned) is that

- it works locally (on your own PC; you have to install it, of course (if you don't have it already). It comes along with any Oracle database (even XE, Express Edition), or is contained in Oracle Client software under its Utilities), while
- for `UTL_FILE` you have to speak to your DBA in order to get access to the directory (usually located on the database server) which would be then used by the named package.

Comment: If the Excel files are XLSX, it's posible to write a PL/SQL package to deal with the files; this files are compress with ZIP and inide is a tree structure of XML files.
XML files can be read using UTL_FILE or read using DBMS_LOB